# Packages for cordova are not loading when deployed to a device

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I've got a Cordova app that works great when deployed to a browser, or simply loaded to a browser. However, when the app is sent to a device via `cordova run android` the plugins are not found.

Using the Chrome remote device inspector, I can see the plugis failing to load in what I would expect to be the normal location.

[image: Cordova Plugins missing]

In the snippet below is a copy of the `config.xml` some items censored.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget defaultlocale="en-US" id="---censored---" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
  <name>---censored---</name>
  <description>---censored---</description>
  <author email="---censored---" href="---censored---">---censored---</author>
  <vs:template-name>BlankJS</vs:template-name>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#fff" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="30" src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="310" src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="44" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="106" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="70" src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="170" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash height="480" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="960" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="768" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1536" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash height="300" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
    <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
  </platform>
  <vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="True" />
  <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
  <engine name="browser" spec="^4.1.0" />
  <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.0" />
  <engine name="windows" spec="~4.4.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
</widget>
```

Cordova.js loads just fine, but I cannot get the plugins to load outside of the browser.

Any direction would be **greatly** appreciated!

**Edit** 
I found some information related to how TACO works, I believe I may be in a situation similar to [this](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-general-readme/#building-a-cordova-project-from-source-control-results-in-a-successful-build-but-with-cordova-plugin-apis-not-returning-results-when-the-app-is-run).

Comment: did you tried removing and re-adding android platform and built android platform again?

Comment: Also looks like none of the plugin got added to the final build. you may have to rebuild the android platform

Comment: @Gandhi I've removed all platforms and re-added them with no change in behavior. How to I add the plugins to the final build?

Comment: If you re-add and build platform, it should take the plugins automatically. Could you post your config.xml? also can you explode you apk file and check whether you got the plugin bundled?

Comment: @Gandhi The config.xml is the code snippet within the question (minimized to de-bloat it). How do I explode the apk file? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @JohnPavek Apks are [basically zip files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package), you can unpack them using a tool like 7zip...

Comment: The plugins are bundled within the apk. ( I just built it)

Comment: @JohnPavek Could you post your html code that loads cordova and plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Cordova generates the plugins, it creates the a folder on the root directory, `plugins`. We were using our own `Plugins` folder to hold some 3rd party JS animation plugins. Due to the case insensitive nature of Windows. There was no error running in the browser.

When deploying to Android Windows would build the files, check for `plugins` and match `Plugins` and move them into there. This is why the  extracted apk file appeared correct. When android sought the files, it didn't match `Plugins` and could not locate my plugins at all.

Long story short, Do not create a folder with a difference case than `plugins` for housing external plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove plugins and re-add them via `cordova plugin add <plugin name>`?

What is `cordova plugin list` output?

What is the output for `cordova build android -XLint:all`?

Check that you've import plugins in your appropriate html file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your config have missing one important plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^3.2.2" />
```

I use 3.2.2 in my config, you can try with the newest version 4.0.3.

You can check also if all plugins are available in plaftorms/android/platform_www/plugins:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the environment information run:

```
ionic info
```

**Does ionic serve give any errors?**
This might be a compatability issue, or a permissions issue. also can you please confirm that the not found files do not exist in the Platform folder?
Go to **platforms>android>platform_www>plugins**
in the worst case I would recommend that you copy your project folder as a backup, go to project directory delete the node_modules folder, the run:

```
npm install
```

this will update the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Cordova CLI to some lower version in config file under Platforms.